# How to protect Foundation\helpers.php file from unwanted changes from client?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using **Laravel 5.2** with **AngularJS**.
I have an application where I'm going to put license functionality in **Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php** file.

I want to protect that file from unwanted changes from end user.

My application is about school. I'm going to generate a license per user.

Can anybody suggest me the best approach to protect my helpers.php file?

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't modify anything in the `vendor` directory. If you need a helper file, create your own in `app/helpers.php` and reference it to your `composer.json` file.

Comment: @fubar You are right. I'm working on products and I want to implement that any way. I saw the same code few days back. Even entering space in helpers.php file took application down. So now I'm thinking to apply same logic in my code.